# Number of additions in a recursive function without using global variables in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, counter, function-pointers

I have to implement a counter that counts the number of additions in this recursive function, but i am not allowed to use global variables. Do you know how to do that? For example if the function has to call itself free times then my counter has to be put on three at the end of the function just before the return.

```
long lindh(unsigned int n) {

  long lin = 0;
  if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
    lin = 1;
  } else {
    lin = 1 * lindh(n - 1) + 3 * lindh(n - 2);
  }

  return lin;
}

int main() {
  long b = 0;
  b = lindh(24);

  cout << "lindhauer " << b << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a parameter to the function?

Comment: Call a "helper" recursive function that takes a count parameter from `lindh`.

Comment: are static variables allowed?
If then just add a static int c = 0; ++i; for the addition.
You have to clear the counter at the beginning of the function though. and the function is not threadsafe in this case

Comment: Scott , yes i am allowed to  change the function as much as necessary

Comment: Philipp, but how can i access to this counter from the main function?

Comment: @ArthurJohnson -- Read my comment.  There is no need to define the counter in the main function or even globally.

Comment: Paul, what do you mean by helper recursive function? so i have to make another function that just counts the number of recursive calls?

Comment: In general, if you have a recursive function that is called with `n` arguments, and you actually need to recursively do things with more than `n` arguments, you create an overloaded version of the recursive function that takes the additional arguments.  The original "recursive" function calls the overloaded function recursively.

Comment: Also, your function returns a `lindh` value.  Maybe your function should return a `std::pair<long, int>` so as to include both `lindh` and `count`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the function signature to be:

```
long lindh(unsigned int n, int &count)
```

Pass it the variable you want the count to end up in, in both the initial call and every recursive one.  Increment `count` in the appropriate places.

Comment: but then i have to give the count to the function in every recursive call again, is this a problem?

Comment: I don't see it as a problem.

Comment: @ArthurJohnson if the compiler can get away with it, a reference parameter won't even have any overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an overloaded `lindh` function that takes two arguments.  The overloaded function takes two parameters, while the version called from `main` is the "base" function that just delegates to the overloaded function.

In addition, since you need to return both a `lin` value and `count`, you can return a `std::pair<long, int>` to denote the `lin` value and count.  This eliminates the need for a global variable,

Here is an example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


long lindh(unsigned int n, int &count) 
{
  long lin = 0;
  if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
    lin = 1;
  } else {
    ++count;
    lin = 1 * lindh(n - 1, count) + 3 * lindh(n - 2, count);
  }
  return lin;
}

std::pair<long,int> lindh(unsigned int n) 
{  
   int count = 0;
   return {lindh(n, count), count};
} 

int main() 
{
   auto b = lindh(24);
   std::cout << "lindhauer = " << b.first << "\ncount = " << b.second << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Example](https://www.ideone.com/BbSmsW)